# smart app banners not working iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, safari, banner

I have wrote this code in HomePage of my website, I am using iOS 6.1.3 in my iPhone 4s
when i access my website in safari initially a banner with loading appears on top of the screen then after some time (means after loading full website) banner gets disappear :(

here is the code i have written in my website,

`<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=68924633, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/bi/id68924637?mt=8&uo=4">`

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: As a guess, your app-argument probably needs to be escaped. Try removing that parameter and see if it displays correctly then.

Comment: DO i need to write any code in my Xcode ?

Comment: You'll need code to understand the app-argument, but there's nothing in Xcode that will determine whether or not the banner itself will display.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had same issue, but it was because the application is only available in US and I'm developing from Colombia. So,  check if you are connected to some VPN or your itunes account is from another region.

I connected my iphone with an US vpn and changed the region of my account and it worked.
Hope it helps!

Comment: yes Dude you are very correct i am developing from india, and app is available only for UK. banner appears in UK

Answer (score 6):

This took a while to work out, but once you have dismissed the popup, it will NOT return. So if your having issues, try on a different phone. Resetting the cache or using private browsing wont help either, as its not stored in cache.

Comment: Was driving myself insane trying to figure out why the banner is not showing anymore. You are 100% correct.

Comment: Thanks, Apple. -__-

Comment: Is there any way to re-enable that after you have dismissed it?

Comment: A factory reset will re-enable the banner.  Very frustrating when testing.

Answer (score 2):

> <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=689246337" />

should be sufficient for your needs

Answer (score 1):

Could be several reasons:
- Your network connection not allowing you to access the apple's appstore, to check this, just open appstore with your phone and see whether it works or not.
- Your apps is not available in the appstore of the country you're connected to, to check this, open appstore from your iphone, and then look for your apps there.

Cheers